# Can Regex groups and * wildcards work together?

Tags: python, regex

Is there any way to combine groups and the * features of regular expressions to act kindof like a tokenizer / splitter.  I tried this:

```
my_str = "foofoofoofoo"
pattern = "(foo)*"
result = re.search(pattern, my_str)
```

I was hoping my groups might look like

```
("foo", "foo", "foo", "foo")
```

But it does not.  I was surprised by this because the ? and group features do work together:

```
my_str= "Mr foo"
pattern = "(Mr)? foo"
result = re.search(pattern, my_str)
```

Comment: I doubt that would work, but you can get what you want using `re.findall("foo", "foofoofoofoo")`. Oh, and please don't use `str` as a variable name.

Comment: I changed `str` to `my_str` since `str` shadows the built-in.

Comment: ha yeah sorry, str was just an example. That code probably is not syntactically correct.  Also, I did see the findall method and that would definitely work. I was just curious in a more general sense.

Comment: @darren http://sscce.org/#co :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is **you repeat your only capturing group**. That means you have only one bracket ==> one capturing group, and this capturing group is overwritten each time when it matches.

See [Repeating a Capturing Group vs. Capturing a Repeated Group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) on regular-expression.info for more information. (But capturing a repeated group is also not what you want)

So, after your regex is done, your capturing group 1 will contain the last found "foo".

This would would give you the expected result:

```
my_str = "foofoofoofoo"
pattern = "foo"
result = re.findall(pattern, my_str)
```

result is then a list `['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo']`

Answer (score 3):

Capture groups and * don't work with the built in re module -- use findall instead.

There is a library called regex in pypi that I believe supports that syntax and has a few other features such as variable length back tracking.

Comment: That would explain things. Thanks.