# Dynamic capture groups in regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

Given the following PHP code:

```
<?php
$str = '/foo/bar/baz';
preg_match('#^(/[^/]+?)*$#', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

...I'm getting the following output:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '/foo/bar/baz' (length=12)
  1 => string '/baz' (length=4)
```

...but I don't understand why.  I would expect each match of `(/[^/]+?)` to be captured into its own group and stuck into `$matches`, such that it looked like this instead:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string '/foo/bar/baz' (length=12)
  1 => string '/foo' (length=4)
  2 => string '/bar' (length=4)
  3 => string '/baz' (length=4)
```

What am I missing?

**Edit:**

This is the output if I use `preg_match_all()` instead, which still isn't what I'm looking for:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '/foo/bar/baz' (length=12)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '/baz' (length=4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the standard behavior of repeated capture groups -- they match all the repetitions, but only capture the last one. See [Can Regex groups and * wildcards work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409236/can-regex-groups-and-wildcards-work-together) for a similar question using Python. I tried it in Perl and got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

preg_match only grabs the first. If you want all of them, use preg_match_all.

**However**: If this is really the exact usecase, use explode() instead.

Comment: That's not what `preg_match_all()` does.  It would give me essentially the same output, split out by matches, but there's only one match.

Comment: I edited the question with the output from `preg_match_all()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
preg_match_all('(/[^/]+)', $str, $matches);
```

Comment: I need to match the whole string, which I can't do using `preg_match_all()`.  For example, `$str = "test/foo/bar/baz"` is invalid, but would still match if I used this.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do with dynamic capture groups is possible in some regex flavours (like C# - [Regular expression with variable number of groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018487/regular-expression-with-variable-number-of-groups) ) , but unfortunately not in PHP.